# Use styling and behavior on tags input that exists on back-end but on a front-end form

Tags: php, wordpress

When editing a post on the back-end, there is nice styling/behavior when entering tags.  When you enter a comma, it styles the tag and adds an "X" if you want to remove the tag from the input:

[image: adding a tag]

Since this already exists, I want to utilize this on a text input on my front-end form.  I was hoping it would be as simple as doing the following:

- create a `div` which wraps the `label` and `input` and add the class: `components-form-token-field`
- create a `div` which wraps the `input` and add the class: `components-form-token-field__input-container`

Unfortunately that didn't do the trick.  I'm guessing that what is likely the issue is that there is some back-end javascript that is not registered in the front-end context.  I'm not sure how to check for this though or how to proceed to problem solve this.

For reference: Here is the output when I inspect the Tag field on the back-end form:
[image: inspect html on tag]

Answer (score 1):

Try using select2 jquery plugin for front-end to achieve the same behavior

Comment: I'm aware of how to bring in other scripts that duplicate this behavior, like "Bootstrap Tags Input."  However: it would be much cleaner to use behavior that is already available.